# Javascript, Open/Close function

Tags: javascript, wordpress, button

I'm very new to using Javascript and i'm struggling how I can achieve what I am after. I've created 4 buttons using;

```
<input type="button" name="answer" value="Brave" onclick="showDiv()">
```

My goal is that if you click on the button, it changes state and the div appears (got that far). If I click another button, i'd like the content to hide the previous div selected and show the one they had just clicked.

Any help/guidance would really be appreciated.

```
function showDiv() {
document.getElementById('BraveDiv').style.display = "block";
}
function showDiv1() {
document.getElementById('DeterminedDiv').style.display = "block";
}
function showDiv2() {
document.getElementById('CompassionateDiv').style.display = "block";
}
function showDiv3() {
document.getElementById('ConsiderateDiv').style.display = "block";
}
```

My aim is that if you was to click

Comment: are you looking for accordion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code attached won't achieve any of the results you're looking for, however, it's obvious what you're looking for.

You buttons should look like the following :

```
<button role="button" onclick="showDiv('BraveDiv')">Brave</button>
```

Here, the role prevents the default behaviour of submit. The onclick tells the button what to do when you click it, and the "BraveDiv" is the parameter we will pass to the function, telling it which div to display.

The DIV associated with the above button, should look as follows :

```
<div id="BraveDiv" style="display: none;"> SOME CONTENT HERE </div>
```

Here you'll notice the ID is equal to the parameter we mentioned above.

And your JavaScript should work as follows :

```
<script>

function showDiv(elem){
document.getElementById(elem).style.display = "block";      

}

</script>
```

I've attached a working snipped example as below, just click "Run code snippet" to view the snippet and test the code.

```js
function showDiv(elem) {
  document.getElementById(elem).style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<button role="button" onclick="showDiv('BraveDiv')">Brave</button>
<button role="button" onclick="showDiv('CompassionateDiv')">Compassionate</button>


<div id="BraveDiv" style="display: none;"> SOME BRAVE CONTENT HERE </div>
<div id="CompassionateDiv" style="display: none;"> SOME COMPASSIONATE CONTENT HERE </div>
```

The above, however, will only SHOW YOUR DIVS.

The full jQuery solution to this (hide/show as per the tag) would be :

```
<script>   

    function showDiv(elem) { // When the button is pressed
    $("div").each(function() { // For each Div
        if ($(this).attr('id') != elem) { // If the Div's id is not equal to the parameter
          $(this).css("display", "none");
        } // HIDE IT
        else {
          $(this).css("display", "block"); // SHow It
        });

</script>
```

If you are unfamiliar with jQuery and would prefer a JavaScript only solution, then :

```
<script>

function showDiv(elem){

var divsToCheck = ["BraveDiv", "CompassionateDiv"]; // Add to here to check more divs
for(let i = 0; i < divsToCheck.length; i++){
if(divsToCheck[i] == elem){
document.getElementById(divsToCheck[i]).style.display = "block";
    }

else{
document.getElementById(divsToCheck[i]).style.display = "none";
    }

}
</script>
```

Again I've attached a snippet below.

```js
function showDiv(elem) {

  var divsToCheck = ["BraveDiv", "CompassionateDiv"]; // Add to here to check more divs
  for (var i = 0; i < divsToCheck.length; i++) {
    if (divsToCheck[i] == elem) {
      document.getElementById(divsToCheck[i]).style.display = "block";
    } else {
      document.getElementById(divsToCheck[i]).style.display = "none";
    }

  }

}
```

```html
<button role="button" onclick="showDiv('BraveDiv')">Brave</button>
<button role="button" onclick="showDiv('CompassionateDiv')">Compassionate</button>


<div id="BraveDiv" style="display: none;"> SOME BRAVE CONTENT HERE </div>
<div id="CompassionateDiv" style="display: none;"> SOME COMPASSIONATE CONTENT HERE </div>
```

Comment: Thank you or this comprehensive answer, and explaining it further.

Comment: If I was to add an extra div would this work the same? For example, I have 4 buttons and 4 divs of content. Is it possible with this method to have an extra div that is visible at the start until a button selection is made?

Comment: @AnthonyCdfWhitefield Correct. Using jQuery you would have to make no changes. With the JavaScript solution, you would simply have to add more values in your array. So instead of var divsToCheck = ["BraveDiv", "CompassionateDiv"]; you would have, var divsToCheck = ["BraveDiv", "CompassionateDiv", "AddedDiv", "MoreDivs", "EvenMoreEtc"];

Simply ensure those strings exist as div IDs. i.e. for every value in the divsToCheck array, make sure a div exists with that ID. Then pass that ID as the parameter to the function.

Answer (score 2):

```
function showDiv() 
{
    document.getElementById('new1').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('Div1').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('Div2').style.display = "none";
}
function showDiv1() 
{
    document.getElementById('Div1').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('new1').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('Div2').style.display = "none";
}
function showDiv2() 
{
    document.getElementById('Div2').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('new1').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('Div1').style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: Please explain your answer

Comment: @mike i created 3 div's and set their display as "none". Now on each button's click i call above written functions setting the display of particular div as "block" and others as "none".

Answer (score 1):

```
function showDiv() {
document.getElementById('BraveDiv').style.display = "block";
document.getElementById('DeterminedDiv').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('CompassionateDiv').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('ConsiderateDiv').style.display = "none";
}
function showDiv1() {
document.getElementById('BraveDiv').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('DeterminedDiv').style.display = "block";
document.getElementById('CompassionateDiv').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('ConsiderateDiv').style.display = "none";
}
function showDiv2() {
document.getElementById('BraveDiv').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('DeterminedDiv').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('CompassionateDiv').style.display = "block";
document.getElementById('ConsiderateDiv').style.display = "none";
}
function showDiv3() {
document.getElementById('BraveDiv').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('DeterminedDiv').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('CompassionateDiv').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('ConsiderateDiv').style.display = "block";
}
```

This might not be the sleekest way of doing it, but will get you the results you want. As each button is pressed, all others will close.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set the `display` style of the remaining `<div>`s back to `none`. The simplest way to do this is to first set *all* of them to `none`, then the one you want visible to `block`:

*Note: I’ve used a function which takes the id of the target `<div>` as a parameter to reduce the amount of code written, but you could easily copy-paste out to separate functions if you require.*

```js
function showDiv(divName) {
  // First hide all the divs
  document.getElementById('BraveDiv').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('DeterminedDiv').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('CompassionateDiv').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('ConsiderateDiv').style.display = 'none';
  
  // Then show the div corresponding to the button clicked
  document.getElementById(divName).style.display = 'block';
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Brave" onclick="showDiv('BraveDiv')">
<input type="button" value="Determined" onclick="showDiv('DeterminedDiv')">
<input type="button" value="Compassionate" onclick="showDiv('CompassionateDiv')">
<input type="button" value="Considerate" onclick="showDiv('ConsiderateDiv')">

<div id="BraveDiv" style="display: none">BraveDiv</div>
<div id="DeterminedDiv" style="display: none">DeterminedDiv</div>
<div id="CompassionateDiv" style="display: none">CompassionateDiv</div>
<div id="ConsiderateDiv" style="display: none">ConsiderateDiv</div>
```

There are alternative ways of doing this which require less code, such as this method using a little CSS and [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll):

```js
function showDiv(divName) {
  // First remove the selected class from all divs in output-divs
  document.querySelectorAll('#output-divs > .selected').forEach(element => {
    element.classList.remove('selected');
  });
  
  // Then add it to the div corresponding to the button clicked
  document.getElementById(divName).classList.add('selected');
}
```

```css
.output-div:not(.selected) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Brave" onclick="showDiv('brave')">
<input type="button" value="Determined" onclick="showDiv('determined')">
<input type="button" value="Compassionate" onclick="showDiv('compassionate')">
<input type="button" value="Considerate" onclick="showDiv('considerate')">

<div id="output-divs">
  <div class="output-div selected" id="brave">Brave</div>
  <div class="output-div" id="determined">Determined</div>
  <div class="output-div" id="compassionate">Compassionate</div>
  <div class="output-div" id="considerate">Considerate</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answer so promptly, this is a massive help!

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn1").click(function(){
        showDiv('div1');
    });
    $("#btn2").click(function(){
        showDiv('div2');
    });
    $("#btn3").click(function(){
        showDiv('div3');
    });
    $("#btn4").click(function(){
        showDiv('div4');
    });    
});

function showDiv(_divId){
 $(".div-class").each(function() {
     if(!$(this).hasClass('div-hide'))
        $(this).addClass('div-hide');
 });
        
 $('#' + _divId).removeClass('div-hide');
}
```

```css
.div-class {
     min-height: 50px;
        border: 1px solid #eee;
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .div-hide {
     display: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button id="btn1">Button 1</button>
<button id="btn2">Button 2</button>
<button id="btn3">Button 3</button>
<button id="btn4">Button 4</button>

<div id="div1" class='div-class div-hide'><h3>Div1 Content </h3></div>
<div id="div2" class='div-class div-hide'><h3>Div2 Content </h3></div>
<div id="div3" class='div-class div-hide'><h3>Div3 Content </h3></div>
<div id="div4" class='div-class div-hide'><h3>Div4 Content </h3></div>
```